# How can I convert a pdf file in a Blob type in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, pdf, .net-core

My project needs to generate a pdf report, and I am using pdfcrowd(https://pdfcrowd.com) to do it.

My approaching is simple and the calling from-end(Angular 7) to the back-end(.Net Core 2.1) is working well,
however, when I receive the pdf in the front end, I am getting the following error.

Return: 200 -Ok

> error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0 at
>   JSON.parse

**My service**

```
GetReportPrint(e: PrintModel) {        
  let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  let body = JSON.stringify(e);
  let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': token
  });

  return this._http.post<any>(
    this.API + 'Report', body, {
      headers: headers,
      responseType: 'blob'
    })
    .pipe(map((response) => {
      let file = response.blob();
      var blob = new Blob([file], {
        type: 'application/pdf'
      });

      FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "tes");
    }))     
}
```

Comment: are you sure the response type is `blob` and not `application/json`?

Comment: Thank you to everyone.

It is working now, tI have committed a huge mistake including the body part inside of the header.



 this.API + 'Report', body, {
      headers: headers,
      responseType: 'blob'
    })

Answer (score 0):

You have problems parsing json, that what is your error is saying.

I would suggest use GET for downloading file instead of POST, try something like:

```ts
this.http.get<any>(url, {responseType: 'blob'}).pipe(..);
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone.

It is working now, tI have committed a huge mistake including the body part inside of the header.



 this.API + 'Report', body, {
      headers: headers,
      responseType: 'blob'
    })

Answer (score 0):

Try this: instead of doing response.blob(), do response.text().

```
.pipe(map((response) => {
  let file = response.text();
  var blob = new Blob([file], {
    type: 'application/pdf'
  });

  FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "test.pdf");
}))
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone.

It is working now, tI have committed a huge mistake including the body part inside of the header.



 this.API + 'Report', body, {
      headers: headers,
      responseType: 'blob'
    })